# How to connect to oracle from a java servlet?

Tags: oracle, servlets, connection

I have a problem connecting to oracle from within a java servlet running in Jetty (as part of Eclipse). The identical code runs fine from a standalone java app.

My entire development environment is on a single mac. I am using Eclipse and have included the ojdbc6.jar in the main 'Referenced Libraries' and have also dragged and dropped this file in the war/web-inf/lib folder.

As soon as the line

> OracleConnectionPoolDataSource ocpds = new
>   OracleConnectionPoolDataSource();

is called (within the servlet) I get the exception:

> java.security.AccessControlException: access denied
>   (javax.management.MBeanServerPermission createMBeanServer)

Am I missing some security policy or so? If so, exactly what do I do need to do to rectify this? And where does this BeanServer come in?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out - not entirely clear why but created a new GWT app in Eclipse but this time NOT included the Google App Engine (which is ticked by default).  This seems to add some restrictions to the code when it is running in Jetty....
I now have copied the sample code over and all is working well!

Answer (score 0):

Every web container has its own way of defining data sources, and making them available through JNDI. You should do that instead.

The native oracle connection pool seems to be creating an MBeanServer, and this is not probably not allowed by the security manager used by Jetty. See http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Secure_Mode and http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Jetty-Policy.

Comment: Thanks for that but I found that on creation of a project when I leave out the Google App Engine it works ok - i.e. my servlet happily connects to oracle and brings back data